# change color of selected tab with dynamic children of top navigation in sharepoint 2013

Tags: top-link-bar

Is there any option to change color of selected tab with dynamic children of top navigation in sharepoint 2013

Comment: how do you want to change the color? i mean on hover or on selection and what do you mean by dynamic children

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried ???

Comment: By dynamic children I just mean links for a heading in top navigation.If link is selected, corresponding heading should be highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I coded my nav. The script will detect which link is clicked and the css will then highlight it. Wrap your navigation with this code in your master page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('nav a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('activeMenu');
});
</script>

<div id="sse50">
  <nav id="sses50">
  <ul>
        <li> <a href="/Page1"><img alt="" src="Navigation/Page1.png" ></a></li>
        <li> <a href="/Page2"><img src="Navigation/Page2.png" ></a></li>
        <li> <a href="/Page3"><img src="Navigation/Page3.png" ></a></li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sse50 
{
  width:90%;
  padding:0px;/*changing its value will give menu margins to its container*/
  text-align:center;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
#sses50
{
  margin:0 auto;/*If you don't want the menu center aligned, remove this line and above  text-align:center*/

}

#sses50 ul, #sses50 li
{
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;padding: 0;margin: 0;border:0;background-image:none;
}

#sses50 a.activeMenu
{
background:#005d84;
border-radius:25px 25px 25px 25px;
margin:7px 0px 7px 0px;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;/*This defines the size of each menu item*/
}
#sse50 img
{
width:100%;
}
#sses50 a
{
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;    
  width:10%;
  opacity: 0.85;
}

#sses50 a:hover, #sses50 a.current
{
/*Hover effect*/
opacity: 1.0; 
background:#005d84;
border-radius:25px 25px 25px 25px;
transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```